# Words to describe the sounds created when having sex

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

This is so embarrassing to ask you about *sound* which is related to having sex.

Is there any sound related to breath? I think "panting" is quite far from implying sex.

I found some words like; boom, bang, smash, thump but I want to find something related to sound.

If I can't find the alternative things, I may use some words like "ah", "mm" ..... so weird.

> You wouldn't dare to say like that, if you know I'm tired of listening your panting every night.

This is what I made, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: *it's about your assignment..* and hence **actually** off topic but I won't vote for closing this (instead, I upvoted!) as this is a good question here.

Comment: I know that grammar is important but the register problem or fleuncy are also important in translation. And that is really difficult to me who is not using enlish as a first language. Anyway thank you so much for your kind answer!XD

Comment: I'd suggest moaning and groaning. They're not onomatopoeia, but I think the phrase works better in your sentence. Also check out the song "Moan & Groan" by Mark Morrison; its lyrics are easy to find on the web (warning, the song's very suggestive).

Comment: @DamkerngT. [That's exactly what I thought. :)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/21256/5251)

Comment: **'moaning and groaning'** can mean 'complaining, griping'.

Comment: The word **say** is incorrect. You mean to say **talk** in your example sentence. And it is **listening to**.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the word `moaning` instead of onomatopoeia or panting.

> <sub>[From Oxford Dictionary; **"moan"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moan?q=moan)</sub>
>
> A long, low **sound made by a person expressing** physical or mental suffering or **sexual pleasure**.

So your sentence becomes:

> I'm tired of listening to your moaning every night.

Comment: True...but there is a bit difference - the OP wants to know any onomatopoeia and not the term for such utterance.

Comment: @MaulikV I was thinking: "People don't know what they want unless you show it to them." - [Steve Jobs](http://www.businessweek.com/bwdaily/dnflash/may1998/nf80512d.htm)

Comment: +1. The example sentence you give is perfectly idiomatic, especially in light of OP's comment: 'And that's the statement of a girl who is insulting her brother`s girlfriend"

Answer (score 0):

They are not typically breathing sounds but an utterance that *may* come with deep breaths.

If you are **looking for an onomatopoeia,** IMO, you may prefer this -

> You wouldnt dare to say like that, if you know I'm tired of listening your **'Aaah's** and **'Yeaaah's** every night.

If you are not writing and speaking this to someone, putting more stresses on those words would convey the message with more clarity.

However, I'm not sure whom are you addressing - a male or female, these onomatopoeia are common and uttered by both equally I guess.

If you are **looking for the terms** to denote these sounds, there are many options depending upon the situation he/she is in! Some of them are *moaning, squeaking, grunting, yelling, whimpering* and so on.

Again, mind it that they are subjective!

[An article on different sounds is here.](http://www.indiansutras.com/spice-up/2012/sounds-men-love-000761.html) A related question is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51304/what-is-the-word-for-the-high-pitched-sex-sound-a-woman-makes).

Comment: Thank you! But I shouldnt say onomatopoeia actually.... Do you know anything like `panting`  which is more related to someone`s status but more strong enough to convey the meaning of intercourse? And that`s a statement of a girl who is insulting her brother`s girlfriend

Comment: @Jay the noun *panting* is breathing heavily especially after exertion and that's not necessarily related to the utterance during the orgasm. The context you describe better take *moaning* as a preferred word I guess.